# Import docx into CKEditor via upload

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'd like to be able to upload the document and set CKEditor's content automatically, instead of copy-pasting a formatted docx file's contents into the editor.

Is this possible through a plugin? Or can I do this myself through some JS manipulation?

I realize I can convert the docx to HTML and assign the content but I'd rather avoid that since CKEditor's copy-paste formatting is great. I want to piggy back off of that to import my formatted docx into the editor instead of having the user copy-paste it manually.

I'm deploying this in a Ruby on Rails application if that makes things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any solution unfortunately. I ended up using `libreoffice --headless --convert-to html example.docx` to do the conversion, then use the HTML it generated directly.

Found libreoffice better than unoconv or abiword for what it's worth.

Comment: Can you explain, how to generate docx to html?

Comment: @Shakthifuture I used [`libreconv`](https://github.com/DocSpring/libreconv) like so `Libreconv.convert(docx_file_path, html_file_path, nil, 'html')` but that was the syntax 5 years ago. Have not used it since